# Render Rally SDK 2.1 in Specific div in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, datatable, rally

In Rally SDK V1.33, I could render a data table like this:

```
...(extra code omitted)
var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config, rallyDataSource);
table.display("tableDiv");
```

and it would be displayed in the specified 'tableDiv' that is already on the page.

In SDK V2.1, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing.  When it renders it takes over the entire page.

I tried adding renderTo to the Ext.define and this.add but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Here is my code:

```
Rally.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('PortfolioItems', {
        extend: 'Rally.app.App',
        componentCls: 'app',
        renderTo: 'tableDiv',

        launch: function() {
            this.drawTypeComboBox();
        },

        drawTypeComboBox: function(){
            this.typeComboBox = this.add({
                xtype: 'rallyportfolioitemtypecombobox',
                renderTo: 'tableDiv'
            });
            this.typeComboBox.on('select', this.drawGrid, this);
            this.typeComboBox.getStore().on('load', this.drawGrid, this);
        },

        drawGrid: function(){
            var selectedType = this.typeComboBox.getRecord();

            Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                type: selectedType.get('TypePath'),
                success: function(model){

                    if(this.grid){
                        this.grid.reconfigureWithModel(model);
                    } else {
                        this.grid = this.add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            renderTo: 'tableDiv',
                            columnCfgs: [
                                "PortfolioItemTypeName",
                                "FormattedID",
                                "Name",
                                "PlannedStartDate",
                                "PlannedEndDate",
                                "PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate",
                                "PercentDoneByStoryCount"
                            ],
                            model: model
                        });

                    }

                },
                scope: this
            });

        }
    });
    Rally.launchApp('PortfolioItems', {
        name: 'Portfolio Items'
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This request comes up periodically for this exact scenario.  The behavior is by design, but you should be able to work around it by just embedding an iframe in your sharepoint control which points to your app's html file served from somewhere on the same server.  Will that work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do that.  There is currently a JS (partial html) file that we are loading in a Content Editor WebPart.  That is the only way our vendor could get it to work for us without cross-site scripting errors.  The div we are trying to attached to is in that file.

Comment: ah.  yeah the html file would need to be hosted on the same domain for sure. i guess i'm not totally sure what you can and can't do in sharepoint.  i know people have had success embedding iframes in other systems like confluence which is why i suggested it here...

Comment: you may try to embed it like this if you can serve external html file from the same server:`<html>
  <header>
    <title>Embedded app test</title>
  </header>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://your_sharepoint_server/App-external.html?apiKey=_abc123"</iframe>
  </body>
</html>`